# Magento 2 - Get abandoned shopping carts through Rest API

Tags: magento2, rest-api, shopping-cart, abandoned-cart

I'm trying to retrieve the abandoned shopping cart through the Magento Rest API. Here is my request

```
https://<my_domain>/rest/V1/carts/search?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=is_active&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=1&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][field]=store_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][value]=1&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][condition_type]=eq&searchCriteria[filter_groups][2][filters][0][field]=items_count&searchCriteria[filter_groups][2][filters][0][value]=0&searchCriteria[filter_groups][2][filters][0][condition_type]=gt
```

I retrieve 514 items.

When I check the report which is available in Magento back-office, it gives me 189 items. I cannot explain the difference.

What should be the request in order to actually retrieve the abandoned shopping carts ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to add the filter on customers:

```
https://<my_domain>/rest/V1/carts/search?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=is_active&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=1&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq&searchCriteria[pageSize]=1&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][field]=store_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][value]=0&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][condition_type]=neq&searchCriteria[filter_groups][2][filters][0][field]=items_count&searchCriteria[filter_groups][2][filters][0][value]=0&searchCriteria[filter_groups][2][filters][0][condition_type]=gt&searchCriteria[filter_groups][3][filters][0][field]=customer_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][3][filters][0][value]=null&searchCriteria[filter_groups][3][filters][0][condition_type]=neq
```